# Fullcalendar not showing data

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, fullcalendar

I'm still a new programmer, and I have a problem getting this piece of code to work (that I got from [here](http://developer-paradize.blogspot.com/2013/06/jquery-fullcalendar-integration-with.html)). It uses MySQL to store the data. I would like to understand all the various parts to this, but I'm just now really starting to understand how ajax and jQuery work together.

It for displaying data, it relies on "events.php". I have run that separately, and it generates JSON that should work for display in the calendar, so I know the SQL works fine, but it won't display on the main page. The paths to the libraries, CSS, and so on have been changed, but the function to insert into the MySQL table works fine... So I can use this to insert dates, but once there, they don't show up on a refresh.

**EDIT: SOLVED. A combination of three problems, as far as I can tell: (1) - Make sure the returned JSON does NOT have quotes around "false". (2) Make sure you have jquery.min.map. (this was found out by looking at the Chrome's debugger), and (3) I could NOT use the file's path... I just refer to it as "events.php".** Thanks to everyone that helped!

Here's the html below... and below THAT, the JSON. I have seen a couple other posts that never had solutions, so obviously, any help GREATLY appreciated:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <script src='lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='lib/jquery-ui.custom.min.js'></script>
    <script src='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {
            var date = new Date();
            var d = date.getDate();
            var m = date.getMonth();
            var y = date.getFullYear();

            var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                editable: true,
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },

                events: "http://localhost/tpsdb/fullcalendar/events.php",

                // Convert the allDay from string to boolean
                eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
                    if (event.allDay === 'true') {
                        event.allDay = true;
                    } else {
                        event.allDay = false;
                    }
                },
                selectable: true,
                selectHelper: true,
                select: function(start, end, allDay) {
                    var title = prompt('Event Title:');
                    var url = prompt('Type Event url, if exits:');
                    if (title) {
                        var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                        var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'http://localhost/tpsdb/fullcalendar/add_events.php',
                            data: 'title='+ title+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end +'&url='+ url ,
                            type: "POST",
                            success: function(json) {
                                alert('Added Successfully');
                            }
                        });
                        calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                                {
                                    title: title,
                                    start: start,
                                    end: end,
                                    allDay: allDay
                                },
                                true // make the event "stick"
                        );
                    }
                    calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
                },

                editable: true,
                eventDrop: function(event, delta) {
                    var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                    var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'http://localhost/tpsdb/fullcalendar/update_events.php',
                        data: 'title='+ event.title+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end +'&id='+ event.id ,
                        type: "POST",
                        success: function(json) {
                            alert("Updated Successfully");
                        }
                    });
                },
                eventResize: function(event) {
                    var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                    var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'http://localhost/tpsdb/fullcalendar/update_events.php',
                        data: 'title='+ event.title+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end +'&id='+ event.id ,
                        type: "POST",
                        success: function(json) {
                            alert("Updated Successfully");
                        }
                    });

                }

            });

        });

    </script>
    <style>

        body {
            margin-top: 40px;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;

        }


        #calendar {
            width: 900px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='calendar'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The JSON generated by the events.php page:

```
[{"id":"7","title":"test","start":"2014-02-05 00:00:00","end":"2014-02-05 00:00:00","url":"","allDay":"false"},{"id":"8","title":"Title 2","start":"2014-02-06 00:00:00","end":"2014-02-06 00:00:00","url":"","allDay":"false"},{"id":"9","title":"Feb 1","start":"2014-01-28 00:00:00","end":"2014-01-28 00:00:00","url":"","allDay":"false"}]
```

Here's the PHP that creates the JSON to strip quotes out as per proper format (true doesn't appear in my JSON string).

```
<?php
    // List of events
    $json = array();

    // Query that retrieves events
    $requete = "SELECT * FROM evenement ORDER BY id";

    // connection to the database
    include ("../includes/functions.php");

    // Execute the query
    $resultat = $bdd->query($requete) or die(print_r($bdd->errorInfo()));

    // sending the encoded result to success page
    $tempjson =  json_encode($resultat->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
    $tempjson = str_replace('"false"', 'false', $tempjson);
    echo $tempjson;

?>
```

More info in my saga - may it help those following in my footsteps: apparently the lib that was provided doesn't include jquery.min.map (I have yet to research what that is). Thanks for asking about the f12 console in Chrome. I saw that the min.map was missing. Still hasn't helped me though :( Working...

Here is the screen shot of Chrome's viewer. 
[image]

Comment: Can you provide the output from your javascript console? If you're using Chrome, you can press F12 to access the dev tools (on Windows).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I found that I was missing jQuery.min.map, so I put that there, though it didn't make it work. Looking at the screenshot I posted, any other suggestions?

Comment: If you click on that red failed request, and you go to the response tab, is there anything there? How about a http response code?

Comment: It says "This request has no response data available". When I changed the "events" line from "localhost:8888/tpsdb..." to the actual web address, it took 23 seconds to generate the error from a (pending) status if that means anything. But still errors... :(

Comment: It may be worthwhile to note this is on a shared hosting service if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replace:

```
 events: "http://localhost/tpsdb/fullcalendar/events.php",
```

with:

```
 eventSources: [

                     {
                         url: 'http://localhost/tpsdb/fullcalendar/events.php',
                         type: 'GET',
                         data: {},
                         error: function () {
                             alert('There was an error while fetching events!');
                         }
                     }
    ],
```

Comment: I just tried this too. I do in fact get an "error while fetching events". I did strip the quotes from the FALSE (that Henrique suggested). No good. Still errors. Something still wrong with the JSON I guess.

Comment: this means the page is not returning the data

Comment: Does that mean the PHP "events.php" file has errors? I run the page by itself, and it outputs the JSON just fine, so it's not a problem with the SQL. I put the entire events.php file up in my original post.

Comment: did you try this , url: 'events.php', i mean correct path with absolute url.

Comment: Yes. The only difference is that it takes about 20 seconds while "events.php" says (pending). Then it says (failed).

Comment: SOLVED. THANK YOU!!!! After banging my head against the wall for so long, I just referred to "events.php" (which is in the same directory), it works. Not to say that I didn't have problems before (like the "false" in quotes, and the missing jquery.map.min), but it all came together. Thanks for helping. I posted this somewhere else too, and the question of cross-domain security came up. Anyway, THANKS AGAIN!

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken this fact into consideration that

Month value is 0-based, meaning January=0, February=1, etc.

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/current_date/month/

So '2014-02-05' will be 5th March.

Comment: Yes. If this is yhe case then it will be visible in other month.

Comment: This is not the case. it shows data in correct month. @APaul

Answer (score 0):

Also modify this:

```
[
{
    "id": "7",
    "title": "test",
    "start": "2014-02-05 00:00:00",
    "end": "2014-02-05 00:00:00",
    "url": "",
    "allDay": false  <-- change this to false without quotes
},
{
    "id": "8",
    "title": "Title 2",
    "start": "2014-02-06 00:00:00",
    "end": "2014-02-06 00:00:00",
    "url": "",
    "allDay": "false"
},
{
    "id": "9",
    "title": "Feb 1",
    "start": "2014-01-28 00:00:00",
    "end": "2014-01-28 00:00:00",
    "url": "",
    "allDay": "false"
}
]
```

Comment: I just tried it. I modified the PHP to strip out the quotes from FALSE and checked the JSON output. It looks OK, but still doesn't work.