# google calendar events don't show to fullcalendar localhost

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to display events from a google calendar in my local site I develop using laravel 5.4. I decided not to try and use a laravel library as I can't find many examples on this.
Anyways, after setting up the calendar, the events I added in the google calendar don't show up.

This is my extremely basic code:

```
@extends('layouts.home')
@section('content')
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            googleCalendarApiKey: 'RemovedSensitiveData',
            events: {
                googleCalendarId: 'mjd3mg13mecqeb3ltcc9n4fmcc@group.calendar.google.com',
                className: 'gcal-event',
                events: 'https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?src=mjd3mg13mecqeb3ltcc9n4fmcc%40group.calendar.google.com&ctz=Europe/Bucharest'
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<div id='calendar'></div>
@stop
```

This is my includes section:

```
{{ Html::style('js/fullcalendar-3.4.0/fullcalendar.css') }}
{{ Html::style('js/fullcalendar-3.4.0/fullcalendar.print.css') }}

{{ Html::script('js/jquery-3.2.0.min.js') }}
{{ Html::script('js/fullcalendar-3.4.0/lib/jquery-ui.min.js') }}
{{ Html::script('js/fullcalendar-3.4.0/lib/moment.min.js') }}
{{ Html::script('js/bootstrap.js') }}
{{ Html::script('js/npm.js') }}
{{ Html::script('js/script.js') }}
{{ Html::script('js/fullcalendar-3.4.0/gcal.js') }}
{{ Html::script('js/fullcalendar-3.4.0/fullcalendar.js') }}
{{ Html::script('js/fullcalendar-3.4.0/fullcalendar.min.js') }}
```

This is what is rendered in the page.
[image: calendar]

This is what I have on my google calendar:
[image: google-calendar]

My google calendar is public.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you're using the right URL. [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/google_calendar/) wants an XML feed, not an entire calendar. Since your calendar is already public, then, you must obtain your calendar's XML feed URL:

```
In the Google Calendar interface, locate the "My Calendar" box on the left
Click the arrow next to the calendar you need.
A menu will appear. Click "Calendar settings."
In the "Calendar Address" section of the screen, click the XML badge.
Your feed's URL will appear.
```

Related threads:

- [Fullcalendar not showing data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21668920/fullcalendar-not-showing-data)
- [FullCalendar: events not rendering initially from function call (AJAX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21707281/fullcalendar-events-not-rendering-initially-from-function-call-ajax)

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you, it sure does help, as I had the wrong link. But it still doesn't work, maybe it's something that's missing and I don't fully understand what needs to be done in order for it to work. I'll study the problem further. thank you for the links, and for your response.

Answer (score 0):

This is something that has changed recently when using FullCalendar with Google Calendars and it took me a while to get it to work so I thought I would share.

What you have as the 'googleCalendarId' is what should be in the 'events' line. So it should be more like this:

```
 googleCalendarApiKey: 'RemovedSensitiveData',
 events: 'mjd3mg13mecqeb3ltcc9n4fmcc@group.calendar.google.com',
```

Here is the demo from the FullCalendar site: https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.5.1/demos/gcal.html

If you 'View Source' you'll see how they structured their code for the demo. I've copied the  below for reference as well.

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,listYear'
        },

        displayEventTime: false, // don't show the time column in list view

        // THIS KEY WON'T WORK IN PRODUCTION!!!
        // To make your own Google API key, follow the directions here:
        // http://fullcalendar.io/docs/google_calendar/
        googleCalendarApiKey: 'AIzaSyDcnW6WejpTOCffshGDDb4neIrXVUA1EAE',

        // US Holidays
        events: 'en.usa#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com',

        eventClick: function(event) {
            // opens events in a popup window
            window.open(event.url, 'gcalevent', 'width=700,height=600');
            return false;
        },

        loading: function(bool) {
            $('#loading').toggle(bool);
        }

    });

});
```